# Selenium : Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

So I'm trying to identify this button to press it, but I get the exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

The image below shows the button:
[image]

The weird thing, is that I already did identify the login button in the login page, but after I got to the following page, it's like identifying an element isn't possible anymore, could that be because the page doesn't allow for that?

```
#This one works
driver.find_element_by_class_name("urBtnStdNew").click()
#This one give the exception
driver.find_element_by_id("sapbi_snippet_TABSTRIP_CONTAINER_ITEM_1").click()
#This is the HTML of that element
<span class="urTbsTxtOff">DPD Trend</span></td>
```

Edit: Thank you guys, I didn't know about iframe's existence, so switching it solved my problem.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='iframe_Roundtrip_9223342']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: PS: It's not a problem of loading time, cause I tried the time.sleep() until the page loads completely and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: is it in an iframe?  if so you will need to switch to the correct iframe before trying to find the element.

Comment: @Ardesco am a total beginner, what's an iframe ? and how can I check ? thank you

Comment: @Ardesco thank you it is indeed an iframe that I had to switch, little did I know about it

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` and following `xpath` to click on the `DPD Trend` tab.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='urTbsLabelOff urBorderBox']/span[@class='urTbsTxtOff'][contains(.,'DPD Trend')]"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried it but I got _selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException_ I don't think it has to do with the page needing time to load, but I think it just can't find the element. what do you think?

Comment: Yes,you are right.However it is difficult to give answer based on snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Hamza,
`WebDriverWait` will not work. As you have stated you have tried using Thread.sleep() and WebDriver still cannot locate the element.

The issue looks to me like it is down to an incorrect element locator being used.

If the button in your screenshot is the one in the red box, and the code in the red box in the element inspector relates to it, then it looks to me like the ID should be `TABSTRIP_CONTAINER_ITEM_1_tabStrip_tabstrip-itm-5`.
So based on your example above the following code should locate the DPD Trend button and click it:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("TABSTRIP_CONTAINER_ITEM_1_tabStrip_tabstrip-itm-5").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried all locators and all values but it always gives (No such element), the page is an SAP BEx webpage so I don't know if it's immune to automation testing...

Comment: It's really a weird button, you can't even "right click" and "open in new tab"

Comment: Is it publicly accessible? Seems very strange that you can't right click it! Perhaps try right clicking on the area around it and then in the element inspector move your mouse on different parts of the code to see if the button is highlighted. Normally works for me when I cant access a certain element.... Failing that, you could create an Iist of all of the tabs (locate them via tagname perhaps) then do an if statement to look at the text of each tab, and click the tab when the text you're searching for is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath locator would be as simple as:

```
//span[text()='DPD Trend']
```

If you will still not be able to locate the element:

- double check that it is not in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), if it is - you will need to [switch to it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) prior to finding
- double check that it is not hidden in the [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), if it is - you will need to locate [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) via [execute_script function](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebDriver.execute_script) and cast the result to a [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)
- a good practice is using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for locating the elements as it might be the case they're not immediately available in DOM, check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more details.